# Way to gather online data/information and report it to a program?

Tags: c#, c++

I asked about this Q format on meta, and the they said that worded correctly, this should be appropriate. This being said, sorry if I still butchered the wording and just in case I'd like to get this across (as was recommended): I'm not looking for opinions on certain things or how they work, rather just the ways it's possible. I don't mean to sound ignorant and I'm truly sorry if I do, it was just suggested to me to say on Meta.

Now for the Q; What just general language at all would be capable of gathering information from public online websites, then putting it in the program where it could be further processed as just any old variable? I'm new to coding and wanted to do this as a little 'introductory' program, to teach myself some new stuff. Problem being, with my idea, I don't even know where to start. Again, I'm not asking for specific ways to do this, I was just curious what languages are capable of doing this at all? I'd prefer to do it in a Visual Studio's language (no preference of which ones), if that's possible.

In short: Are either Visual C#/C++ capable of gathering information online to be further handled within the program? If not, what languages are?

Comment: I think pretty much any language would be capable of doing that, including the two you mentioned. Which you choose depends on many factors but primary is what language you feel most comfortable with. But I think you have chosen something far far too difficult as your first programming task.

Comment: Okay, thanks. No libraries required or anything?

Comment: You are very likely to need a library, parsing HTML (which is what you are basically talking about) is a difficult task.

Comment: Okay, thanks a million. That answers my question perfectly, so you could write that all down in an answer if you so please, haha. Thanks a million

Comment: Well I mean I've done silly little calculators, and all that, but I want something that actually has a purpose outside of me just being able to say I did it. @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: If you want to use information for something - look at HtmlAgilityPack - you should be able to write reasonable crawler and than read data... Since you don't like parsing (based on "silly little calculators") learning how to read HTML from scratch will not make you happy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment that this is a complicated first programming task. However, you'll undoubtedly learn something trying it.

If you already had some experience programming in Python, I'd suggest you took a look at http://scrapy.org/doc/ which is a framework (that is, a bunch of classes and other useful tools) which let you write programs to extract information from web pages. Scrapy does let you concentrate on programming by taking care of some of the nasty details involved in parsing web pages.

Another option is to use a javascript framework, maybe something like node.js.

I've done a fair amount of web scraping, and I usually end up using a combination of utilities which clean up web pages and a variety of XSLT processors. I personally find that combination of technology to be easier to deal with; I don't try to use C-family languages until I've basically wrestled the data into shape. But everyone has their own style.

Good luck!